# Convert a list to a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

How do I convert a list to a string in C#?

When I execute `toString` on a List object, I get:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: A List is a collection, what is this string supposed to look like?

Comment: You can try any of the three ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142321/465053).

Comment: @Marko like in java? `["element1","element2"]`

Comment: @Niton: What Marko is trying to saying is that there is a bit of ambiguity about what a List string is supposed to look like. In the example you gave, all the items look like strings. However, lists can also be made of objects, which may or may not have their own toString functions.
I found this question by searching for the very same thing.

Answer (score 587, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to do:

```csharp
string combinedString = string.Join( ",", myList.ToArray() );
```

You can replace `,` with whatever character you want to split the elements in the list by.

Also, as mentioned in the comments you could also do:

```csharp
string combinedString = string.Join( ",", myList);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join#system-string-join(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))):

> `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)`
>
> Concatenates the members of a constructed [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-7.0) collection of type [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0), using the specified separator between each member.

Comment: do you mean 

    string combindedString = string.Join( ",", myList.ToArray());

Comment: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: I used this recently, it works - just omit the .ToArray()

Comment: @AdrianK you are correct because the .Net 4.0 added the ability to pass in any IEnumerable<string>.  However 4.0 was released in April 2010, before this question and answer were posted so perhaps the folks here were just not yet aware of it (other than a few down below)

Comment: For vb.net, Dim combindedString As String = String.Join(",", myList.ToArray())

Answer (score 62):

I am going to go with my gut feeling and assume you want to concatenate the result of calling `ToString` on each element of the list.

```
var result = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
```

Comment: You don't have to use `.ToArray()` anymore.

Answer (score 24):

You could use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Green"
};

string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.ToArray());    
Console.Write(output);
```

**The result would be:**

```
Red    
Blue    
Green
```

As an alternative to [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx), you can replace it with a string based line-separator of your choosing.

Answer (score 15):

`String.Join(" ", myList)` or `String.Join(" ", myList.ToArray())`. The first argument is the separator between the substrings.

```
var myList = new List<String> { "foo","bar","baz"};
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("-", myList)); // prints "foo-bar-baz"
```

Depending on your version of .NET you might need to use ToArray() on the list first..

Answer (score 14):

If you want something slightly more complex than a simple join you can use LINQ e.g.

```
var result = myList.Aggregate((total, part) => total + "(" + part.ToLower() + ")");
```

Will take ["A", "B", "C"] and produce "(a)(b)(c)"

Comment: Use Aggregate with a seed as the first parameter to avoid throwing InvalidOperationException for empty collections.

Answer (score 11):

You have a `List<string>` - so if you want them concatenated, something like

```
string s = string.Join("", list);
```

would work (in .NET 4.0 at least). The first parameter is the delimiter. So you could also comma-delimit etc.

You might also want to look at using StringBuilder to do running concatenations, rather than forming a list.

Answer (score 10):

The `.ToString()` method for reference types usually resolves back to `System.Object.ToString()` unless you override it in a derived type (possibly using extension methods for the built-in types).  The default behavior for this method is to output the name of the type on which it's called.  So what you're seeing is expected behavior.

You could try something like `string.Join(", ", myList.ToArray());` to achieve this.  It's an extra step, but it could be put in an extension method on `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` to make it a bit easier.  Something like this:

```
public static class GenericListExtensions
{
    public static string ToString<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", list);
    }
}
```

(Note that this is free-hand and untested code.  I don't have a compiler handy at the moment.  So you'll want to experiment with it a little.)

Comment: it does work when I call it not ToString or execute it with generic parameter. But I like your idea of using extension method :)

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to tell, but perhaps you're looking for something like:

```
var myString = String.Join(String.Empty, myList.ToArray());
```

This will implicitly call the ToString() method on each of the items in the list and concatenate them.

Comment: `String.Concat()` will achieve the same thing better.

Comment: @JeffMercado https://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/c-string-concat-vs-string-join/

Answer (score 4):

This method helped me when trying to retrieve data from Text File and store it in Array then Assign it to a string avariable.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Notes.txt");  
string marRes = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```

Hopefully may help Someone!!!!

Answer (score 3):

If your list has fields/properties and you want to use a specific value (e.g. FirstName), then you can do this:

```
string combindedString = string.Join( ",", myList.Select(t=>t.FirstName).ToArray() );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to turn the items in a list into a big long string, do this:  `String.Join("", myList)`.  Some older versions of the framework don't allow you to pass an IEnumerable as the second parameter, so you may need to convert your list to an array by calling .ToArray().

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is `String.Join` as others have mentioned.

However, if you need some manipulations, you can use `Aggregate`:

```
List<string> employees = new List<string>();
employees.Add("e1");
employees.Add("e2");
employees.Add("e3");

string employeesString = "'" + employees.Aggregate((x, y) => x + "','" + y) + "'";
Console.WriteLine(employeesString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: in production code make sure your list have any element otherwise it will throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me.

```
var combindedString = new string(list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

**String.Join**

*We can simply convert into a single string using string.join method. The join method concatenate a list of strings into a single string.*

```
string result = String.Join(",", myList);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your answer doesn't provide more information than the existing answers, I think you should read the [help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons leading to answer deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -4):

```
string strs="111,222,333"
string.Join(",",strs.Split(',').ToList().Select(x=>x.PadLeft(6,'0')).ToArray());
```

The output

```
000111,000222,000333
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation as well, not just code.

Comment: The question is not about a comma-separated string, but a `List<string>`