# Is the string ctor the fastest way to convert an IEnumerable<char> to string

Tags: c#, performance

**Edited for the release of .Net Core 2.1**

Repeating the test for the release of .Net Core 2.1, I get results like this

> 1000000 iterations of "Concat" took 842ms.
>
> 1000000 iterations of "new String" took 1009ms.
>
> 1000000 iterations of "sb" took 902ms.

In short, if you are using .Net Core 2.1 or later, `Concat` is king.

---

I've **edited** the question to incorporate the valid points raised in the comments.

---

I was musing on [my answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10244306/659190) and I started to wonder, is this,

```
return new string(charSequence.ToArray());
```

The best way to convert an `IEnumerable<char>` to a `string`. I did a little search and found this question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654190/ienumerablechar-to-string). That answer asserts that,

```
string.Concat(charSequence)
```

is a better choice. Following an answer to this question, a `StringBuilder` enumeration approach was also suggested,

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in chars)
{
    sb.Append(c);
}

return sb.ToString();
```

while this may be a little unwieldy I include it for completeness. I decided I should do a little test, the code used is at the bottom.

When built in release mode, with optimizations, and run from the command line without the debugger attached I get results like this.

> 1000000 iterations of "Concat" took 1597ms.
>
> 1000000 iterations of "new String" took 869ms.
>
> 1000000 iterations of "sb" took 748ms.

To my reckoning, the `new string(...ToArray())` is close to twice as fast as the `string.Concat` method. The `StringBuilder` is marginally faster still but, is awkward to use but could be an extension.

Should I stick with `new string(...ToArray())` or, is there something I'm missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        const int iterations = 1000000;
        const string testData = "Some reasonably small test data";

        TestFunc(
            chars => new string(chars.ToArray()),
            TrueEnumerable(testData),
            10,
            "new String");

        TestFunc(
            string.Concat,
            TrueEnumerable(testData),
            10,
            "Concat");

        TestFunc(
            chars =>
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var c in chars)
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            },
            TrueEnumerable(testData),
            10,
            "sb");

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

        TestFunc(
            string.Concat,
            TrueEnumerable(testData),
            iterations,
            "Concat");

        TestFunc(
            chars => new string(chars.ToArray()),
            TrueEnumerable(testData),
            iterations,
            "new String");

        TestFunc(
            chars =>
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var c in chars)
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            },
            TrueEnumerable(testData),
            iterations,
            "sb");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static TResult TestFunc<TData, TResult>(
            Func<TData, TResult> func,
            TData testData,
            int iterations,
            string stage)
    {
        var dummyResult = default(TResult);

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            dummyResult = func(testData);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} iterations of \"{2}\" took {1}ms.",
            iterations,
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            stage);

        return dummyResult;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> TrueEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        foreach (var t in sequence)
        {
            yield return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.) If this was done in Debug mode, the results are inaccurate and have to be tossed. 2.) This sounds like [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization). If it hasn't caused a performance hit (and I'm sure it hasn't), what does testing the performance solve?

Comment: Side note: consider testing on something that is true `IEnumerable` (i.e. `Enumerable.Repeat('d', 100)`) to avoid potential shortcuts in constructors/conversion methods.

Comment: To add to @DaveZych comment, you need to test in release mode *without the debugger attached*: Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JimMischel, you make a good point, I've tested in release mode without the debugger attached to get the results I state.

Comment: @DaveZych, 1) see my previous response above. 2) The purpose of the test is to answer the question. Given a number of choices that are all easy to use is speed or performance a bad differentiator?

Comment: you have a fourth option: `string.Join("", charSequence)`. I expect it to be close to constructor/string builder performance

Answer (score 7):

It's worth noting that these results, whilst true for the case of IEnumerable from a purists point of view, are not always thus. For example if you were to actually have a char array even if you are passed it as an IEnumerable it is faster to call the string constructor.

The results:

```
Sending String as IEnumerable<char> 
10000 iterations of "new string" took 157ms. 
10000 iterations of "sb inline" took 150ms. 
10000 iterations of "string.Concat" took 237ms.
======================================== 
Sending char[] as IEnumerable<char> 
10000 iterations of "new string" took 10ms.
10000 iterations of "sb inline" took 168ms.
10000 iterations of "string.Concat" took 273ms.
```

The Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestCreation(10000, 1000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void TestCreation(int iterations, int length)
{
    char[] chars = GetChars(length).ToArray();
    string str = new string(chars);
    Console.WriteLine("Sending String as IEnumerable<char>");
    TestCreateMethod(str, iterations);
    Console.WriteLine("===========================================================");
    Console.WriteLine("Sending char[] as IEnumerable<char>");
    TestCreateMethod(chars, iterations);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void TestCreateMethod(IEnumerable<char> testData, int iterations)
{
    TestFunc(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()), testData, iterations, "new string");
    TestFunc(chars =>
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in chars)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }, testData, iterations, "sb inline");
    TestFunc(string.Concat, testData, iterations, "string.Concat");
}
```

Comment: Your results are similar to my results. Apart from `string.Concat` being marginally easier to type, I see no reason why I should use it in place of `new string(...ToArray())`.

Comment: I guess the key is for people to understand the options. If you genuinely have an IEnumerable and performance is that much of a concern then I think I would go to the effort of having an extension method to use a string builder but if you know you have an array then clearly the best option is to use the string constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just wrote up a little test, trying 3 different ways of creating a string from an IEnumerable:

1. using `StringBuilder` and repeated invocations of its `Append(char ch)` method.
2. using `string.Concat<T>`
3. using the `String` constructor.

10,000 iterations of generating a random 1,000 character sequence and building a string from it, I see the following timings in a release build:

- Style=StringBuilder
  elapsed time is 00:01:05.9687330 minutes.
- Style=StringConcatFunction
  elapsed time is 00:02:33.2672485 minutes.
- Style=StringConstructor
  elapsed time is 00:04:00.5559091 minutes.

`StringBuilder` the clear winner. I'm using a static `StringBuilder` (singleton) instance, though. Dunno if that makes much difference.

Here's the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
  class Program
  {

    static readonly RandomNumberGenerator Random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create() ;

    static readonly byte[] buffer = {0,0} ;

    static char RandomChar()
    {
      ushort codepoint ;
      do
      {
        Random.GetBytes(buffer) ;
        codepoint = BitConverter.ToChar(buffer,0) ;
        codepoint &= 0x007F ; // restrict to Unicode C0 ;
      } while ( codepoint < 0x0020 ) ;
      return (char) codepoint ;
    }

    static IEnumerable<char> GetRandomChars( int count )
    {
      if ( count < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count") ;

      while ( count-- >= 0 )
      {
        yield return RandomChar() ;
      }
    }

    enum Style
    {
      StringBuilder = 1 ,
      StringConcatFunction = 2 ,
      StringConstructor = 3 ,
    }

    static readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
    static string MakeString( Style style )
    {
      IEnumerable<char> chars = GetRandomChars(1000) ;
      string instance ;
      switch ( style )
      {
      case Style.StringConcatFunction :
        instance = String.Concat<char>( chars ) ;
        break ;
      case Style.StringBuilder : 
        foreach ( char ch in chars )
        {
          sb.Append(ch) ;
        }
        instance = sb.ToString() ;
        break ;
      case Style.StringConstructor :
        instance = new String( chars.ToArray() ) ;
        break ;
      default :
        throw new InvalidOperationException() ;
      }
      return instance ;
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch() ;

      foreach ( Style style in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Style)) )
      {
        stopwatch.Reset() ;
        stopwatch.Start() ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; ++i )
        {
          MakeString( Style.StringBuilder ) ;
        }
        stopwatch.Stop() ;
        Console.WriteLine( "Style={0}, elapsed time is {1}" ,
          style ,
          stopwatch.Elapsed
          ) ;
      }
      return ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When the `StringBuilder` is instantiated it needs to allocate memory. This time should be accounted for in the string builder approach. It also looks like you are throwing a random mnumber of expensive exceptions in the string generation. The test could/should be conducted on the same string. While the length could be a siginificant factor I don't think randomness of content is relavent here.

Comment: the questions still stands though: *Should [the OP] stick with new string(...ToArray()) or, is there something [he's] missing?*

Comment: This code has **huge bugs**. The call to `MakeString(Style.StringBuilder);` should be `MakeString(style);`, otherwise you're just comparing the `StringBuilder` method to itself! You got different timings because each `foreach` iteration gets slower as your shared `StringBuilder` grows ever larger; if you create a new instance for each value of `style` then (with the other bug) the tests yield similar timings. After fixing the `MakeString()` call with Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.5/.NET v4.7.1 I get `StringBuilder=0:59.41`, `StringConcatFunction=6:13.75`, and `StringConstructor=7:56.22`. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Also, it's not fair to use a shared `StringBuilder` because `instance = sb.ToString();` produces an incorrect (cumulative) `string` for every call but the first. To fix this, on each call `MakeString()` should either call `sb.Clear()` (for single-threaded code) or create its own local `StringBuilder` (for multi-threaded code), in which case I get `StringBuilderSingleInstanceCleared=2:44.31` and `StringBuilderInstancePerCall=4:27.73`. Ultimately, your conclusion was still correct, though the `StringBuilder` method is more like 1.4x-2.9x, not 2.4x-3.7x, as fast as other methods.