# Convert Byte Array to string of numbers [c#]

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I need help with convert numbers from byte array to string in C#.

There is my code:

```
string Astr = "123456789";
byte[] AByte = Astr.Select(c => (byte)(c - '0')).ToArray(); 
Astr = AByte.ToString(); // This is problem - I need convert numbers back to string
```

Thank you for yours ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this,

```
Astr = new String(AByte.Select (b=>(Char)(b+ 48)).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = string.Concat(AByte);
```

[The overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828.aspx) used was new in .NET 4.0 (2010).

This works only if all values in the array are in the range `(byte)0` through `(byte)9`. As pointed out in the comments, nine string instances will be created. However, no lambda (anonymous function) or intermediate array is used.

Comment: You need to account for the `c - '0'` of the original code. Also, I think Concat<T> will call tostring on each char, thus making 9 separate string instances before they are concatenated together.

Answer (score -1):

A reasonably efficient approach would be to use the `String` constructor that takes a char array. Then you simply need to use `Select` to map your values into the original char values, and call `ToArray()`.

```
string originalString = new String(AByte.Select(x => (char)(x + '0')).ToArray());
```

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778840/is-the-string-ctor-the-fastest-way-to-convert-an-ienumerablechar-to-string) suggests that using a StringBuilder in a loop could be marginally faster, however, I don't think it's worth it unless you know you have a bottleneck.

Comment: There is no String constructor taking IEnumerable

Comment: Argh, didn't they add that yet ? ;-) Fixed the answer.

Comment: Downvoting. This creates an extra redundant array.

Comment: It's better than 9 redundant strings. Not downvoting your answer though.

Comment: Hmm, you are right about the strings in my answer. However I avoid 9 additions, a lambda and an extra array.

Comment: But the code in your answer doesn't work, you need to add the 48 ( `0` ) back in to get the original string, unless the problem space is limited to digits :-) Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778840/is-the-string-ctor-the-fastest-way-to-convert-an-ienumerablechar-to-string - tl;dr: This is fast, throwing in a stringbuilder would be marginally faster.

Comment: No, subtracting `'0'` (in the expression `c - '0'` of the question) is really just a "smart" way of doing `byte.Parse(c.ToString())`.

Comment: @driis  `But the code in your answer doesn't work, you need to add the 48 ( 0 ) back in to get the original string` Have you tried before commenting?

Comment: @L.B ... `unless the problem space is limited to digits`

Comment: @driis Then I should ask, have you read the question. How the OP forms that byte array.