# How to get the max character on each position for a List<string> in .NET (without looping)?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following code:

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "012abc", "120ccc", "000aaa" };
var str = strings.Select(x => x.ToCharArray());
```

I need to get the max string on each position returned as a string.

- Position 1: 0, 1 and 0 = 1
- Position 2: 1, 2 and 0 = 2

Resulting string should be: 122ccc.

Is there a Lambda / Linq query that can be used for this or do I just need to loop through each character?

Comment: Can you share your attempt with a loop logic? Also, I think you should add more examples. Can you detail your "Position" logic?

Comment: What makes it the "max character"? ascii num? hex value?

Comment: Are all strings always of equal length?

Comment: All strings are always the same length. Type on each position is always the same. If position 1 is numeric in the first string, the rest will also be strings. Type can be numeric [0-9] or lowercase letter [a-z].

Comment: I'd just use a normal loop for this.

Comment: A Linq query would still be using a loop, you're really just complicating things with Linq here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposed that length of all strings is equal

**Solution 1**: without using Linq.

The idea is: Get `max` char at the position `i` in the loop

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "012abc", "120ccc", "000aaa" };
var arrays = strings.Select(x => x.ToCharArray());

var charResult = new List<char>();

for(int i = 0; i < strings.First().Length;i++)
{
    charResult.Add(arrays.Select(x=> x[i]).Max());
}
```

Output :

```
122ccc
```

**Solution 2**: with Linq

The fiddle works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MPA8RA

The idea: use `Aggregate` to compare each pair of char[].

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "012abc", "120ccc", "000aaa" };
var arrays = strings.Select(x => x.ToCharArray());          

var charResult = arrays.Aggregate((a, b) => b.Select((t,i) => (char)Math.Max(t, a[i])).ToArray());          

Console.Write(new string(charResult.ToArray()));
```

Output :

```
122ccc
```

Comment: "without looping"

Comment: Nice use of Aggregate :) Note that you can replace `new string(charResult.ToArray())` with `string.Concat(charResult)`

Comment: As an experiment in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584267/6230863 , new string is the fastest way. So, I like to use it

Comment: You don't need `arrays = strings.Select(x => x.ToCharArray());` - you can just use `strings` where you are using `arrays`. That will save a few cycles. Also instead of `strings.First().Length` you can just use `strings[0].Length`

Comment: `As an experiment in my answer stackoverflow.com/a/51584267/6230863 , new string is the fastest way` I looked at your test code, but I note that it does not account for the extra pressure on the GC caused by creating an additional array with the `.ToArray()` so therefore the results are a little suspect IMO.