# Convert List elements to String

Tags: c#, list, typeconverter

What is the best way to convert list of Int32 to a string with a separator like ',' in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981390/how-to-convert-list-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `string.Join`:

```
var intList = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = string.Join(",", intList);
```

**Edit:**

If you are from .NET 4.0, `string.Join` accepts input parameter as `IEnumerable<T>`, so you don't need to convert to `Array` by `ToArray`.

But if you are in .NET 3.5: like other answers, `ToArray` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

```
string Result = string.Join(",", MyList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

Join on a string: `String.Join(",", list.ToArray());`

Answer (score 2):

```
string commaSeparated = String.Join(",", Intlist.ToArray());
```