# Serialise a property of a class to a seperated string

Tags: c#, string, list

What I want to do is similar to this, except that I have a more complex class (with multiple properties).

[Convert a list to a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981390/convert-a-list-to-a-string-in-c-sharp)

I have a class with multiple properties which is stored in a list

While populating this list, I also populate a `|` seperated string with the name property, which is subsequently used by regex

So, can I just populate the list, and afterwards, easily build a `|` seperated string from the `Name` property of the class in the list?

Example Code

Class being populated:

```
public class Thing
{
    public MyParentClass parent;
    public string Name;         
    public List<string> OtherThings = new List<string>();

    public Thing(string path)
    {
        // Here I set the Name property to the filename
        Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    }

}
```

Populating code:

```
public List<Thing> Stuff = new List<Thing>();
public string AllThings = "";

void GetThings(files)
{
foreach (string f in files)
    {
        Stuff.Add(f)
        AllThings  = AllThings + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) + "|";
    }
}
```

So what I want to know is: Can I remove the `AllThings  = AllThings +` line and instead populate AllThings after all the classes are loaded?

If I try something like this:

```
AllCubes = string.Join("|", Stuff.ToArray());
```

I get

> CS0121    The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'string.Join(string, params object[])' and
>   'string.Join(string, IEnumerable)'

Which is no suprise as I know it's not that simple - I just wanted to try and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `String.Join` work you will need to provide a collection of strings, not a custom type.

Ambiguity is due to covariance, since it can implicitly become an `object` or `string` in this case.

So instead of your approach go ahead with explicitly stating that it will be `string` and pushing certain property of `object` as that `string`:

`AllCubes = string.Join("|", Stuff.Select(x => x.Name));`.

This will provide an `IEnumerable` of `strings` which meets contract requirements `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, it most certainly is.