# How to print all the list values which is a dynamic list of strings

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, dynamic

I have a below dictionary.

1. How to print dictionary values which is a list of strings as t1, t2 & t3?
2. I could also use `Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, string>>`. Which one is better - tuple or dynamic?

```c#
Dictionary<string, dynamic> Dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
            {
                {
                    "testKey",
                    new List<string> { "t1", "t2", "t3" }
                }
            };

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> kvp in Dict)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("dictionary.txt", string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value, Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list to a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981390/convert-a-list-to-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Tuples are serialized ugly, as their structure is design-time only. But this is the less expensive data representation available. You either need reflection to print tuple elements or if the structure is well known, juts format it directly.

Comment: Instead of the tuple or the dynamic object, it could be clearer if you use a class.

Comment: Why do you wish to use `dynamic` vs `List<string>`?

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies! Seriously, there's almost always a better way.

Comment: Which is better? Probably neither. Use `List<string>` if the number of items is variable, `ValueTuple` if not (`Dictionary<string, (string one, string two, string three)>`). Of course, making your own little class to hold data is always an option as well.

Comment: I recommend csv format for this type of requirements.