# convert an object (list of strings) into data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am working in C# and .net core. I have an object which consist of multiple lists of strings and i want to convert this object into datatable.

I have tried this code, but it failed:

```
public static DataTable ObjectToData(object o)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("OutputData");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    o.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(f =>
    {
        try
        {
            f.GetValue(o, null);
            dt.Columns.Add(f.Name, typeof(string));
            dt.Rows[0][f.Name] = f.GetValue(o, null);
        }
        catch { }
    });
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Please amend your question to at least show what you have been working with.

Comment: Update. I am get System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] this in row as data

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981390/convert-a-list-to-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: remove the try catch is hiding the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic convertion:

```
public DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
               row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you add the `DataRow` at the start of it. what you have to do is instanciate it, and then assign the values and finally add  it to the datatable. 
Also change the add information into the row for the next `dr[f.Name] = f.GetValue(o, null);`

here is the code:

```
public static DataTable ObjectToData(object o)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("OutputData");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();


    o.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(f =>
    {
        try
        {
            f.GetValue(o, null);
            dt.Columns.Add(f.Name, typeof(string));
            dr[f.Name] = f.GetValue(o, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    });

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt;
}
```

you can find an example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/EeegHg