# Is there a C# equivalent to Python's pprint?

Tags: python, c#, pprint

More specifically, I have an collection of string elements in C# that I want to print out like so:

```
{ "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3" }
```

Is there a library already built to do this? I know I could write a little bit of code for myself but I am curious. In python, if I had a list, I could easily print out the list with nice formatting like so.

```python
import pprint
my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'cats', 'dogs'] 
pprint.pprint(my_list)
```

which would yield me `['foo', 'bar', 'cats', 'dogs']` to the console.

Comma separated values are fine, I do not *need* the curly brackets or other formatting.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. I do not *need* the curly brackets.

Comment: Hey @Jack, Can you update your question and mention  your requirement of comma separated values. I guess your question description is not conveying it properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981390/convert-a-list-to-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that earlier post, it's just one of those days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [string.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__),

> Concatenates the members of a constructed IEnumerable collection of
> type String, using the specified separator between each member.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...
var result = string.Join(", ", my_list);  //Concatenate my_list elements using comma separator
Console.WriteLine(result);               //Print result to console
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N0QP99)