# How to display a list of a model in a C# console application

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I have been struggling to do the following:
I'm trying to List a list in a console application, I have a model called "TeamModel"

```
public class TeamModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public List<PersonModel> TeamMembers { get; set; } = new List<PersonModel>();

    public TeamModel()
    {

    }
}
```

---

In my main class I have the following:

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TeamModel> TeamOne   = new List<TeamModel>(){new TeamModel() { Id =1, TeamName = "x's Team", TeamMembers  = null}};
        List<TeamModel> TeamTwo   = new List<TeamModel>(){new TeamModel() { Id =2, TeamName = "y's Team", TeamMembers  = null}};
        List<TeamModel> TeamThree = new List<TeamModel>(){new TeamModel() { Id =3, TeamName = "z's Team", TeamMembers  = null}};

        List<List<TeamModel>> listOfTeams = new List<List<TeamModel>> (){TeamOne,TeamTwo,TeamThree};

        foreach (List<TeamModel> list in listOfTeams) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now when I run the program I expect the result to be:

1,x's Team ,
2,y's Team ,
3,z's Team

Instead what I'm getting is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TeamModel]  
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TeamModel]  
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TeamModel]
```

---

If I change the foreach to :

```
foreach (List<TeamModel> list in listOfTeams) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list));
}
```

---

I get this:

TeamModel
TeamModel
TeamModel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list to a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981390/convert-a-list-to-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You've actually got a list of lists.  Therefore your code won't correctly print the contents of the inner list.  Gabriel's answer below will work.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: @swatsonpicken yes both yours and Gabriel. thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason that TeamOne, TeamTwo and TeamThree are created as lists given that each "list" contains a single team? The following implementation would achieve what you stated was the expected output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TeamModel TeamOne = new TeamModel { Id = 1, TeamName = "x's Team", TeamMembers = null };
    TeamModel TeamTwo = new TeamModel { Id = 2, TeamName = "y's Team", TeamMembers = null };
    TeamModel TeamThree = new TeamModel { Id = 3, TeamName = "z's Team", TeamMembers = null };

    List<TeamModel> listOfTeams = new List<TeamModel> { TeamOne, TeamTwo, TeamThree };

    foreach (TeamModel team in listOfTeams)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"{team.Id}. {team.TeamName}");
    }
}
```

If you genuinely need a list of lists then the following implementation will work. The only difference from your own solution is an additional `foreach` inside the one you had:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<TeamModel> TeamOne = new List<TeamModel>() { new TeamModel() { Id = 1, TeamName = "x's Team", TeamMembers = null } };
    List<TeamModel> TeamTwo = new List<TeamModel>() { new TeamModel() { Id = 2, TeamName = "y's Team", TeamMembers = null } };
    List<TeamModel> TeamThree = new List<TeamModel>() { new TeamModel() { Id = 3, TeamName = "z's Team", TeamMembers = null } };

    List<List<TeamModel>> listOfTeams = new List<List<TeamModel>>() { TeamOne, TeamTwo, TeamThree };

    foreach (List<TeamModel> list in listOfTeams)
    {
        foreach (TeamModel team in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{team.Id}. {team.TeamName}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using

```
foreach (List<TeamModel> list in listOfTeams) 
{
  foreach (var team in list)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(team.Id + " " + team.Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Using Linq

You can Flatten the nested list using [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) and then either you can iterate over flatten list or you can convert it into List of string and then print it.

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
> the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
var strTeamDetails =  listOfTeams
         .SelectMany(teams => teams)  //Flatten the List.
         .Select(individualTeam => $"{individualTeam.Id} {individualTeam.Name}");  //Convert to IEnumearable of string

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",\n", strTeamDetails)); //Print
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [overriding the ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method for your TeamModel class;

From the link above;

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

You can test the ToString method as shown in the following code example:

```
Person person = new Person { Name = "John", Age = 12 };
Console.WriteLine(person);
// Output:
// Person: John 12
```